# Bash - PS1 not Updating With Proper Hostname after Hostname Change in Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rhel

I want to run a script that changes the hostname and have my bash prompt (PS1 variable) update immediately with the proper hostname.  How do I make this happen?

I run this

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./changehost <newhostname>

#Do two sed's to edit the files for persistent hostname change
sed -i s/$(hostname)/$1/g "/etc/hosts"
sed -i s/$(hostname)/$1/g "/etc/sysconfig/network"

#run the hostname command with new hostname to update it
hostname $1
```

In a terminal like so and get this

```
[user@host dir]# ./changehost newhostname
[user@host dir]#
```

But what I want is this

```
[user@host dir]# ./changehost newhostname
[user@newhostname dir]#
```

The terminal is updated properly only when I open up a new shell.  I've tried re-exporting the PS1 variable, and sourcing the /etc/bashrc in and out of the script (after it is run).

To reiterate, how do I get the shell that I run it in to update immediately?